# i have a 2008 chevy trailblazer 4.2 i need to change the ECT sensor

Tags: chevrolet, sensor, trailblazer, ect

I can not seem to locate the part on my vehicle  i have looked at you tube videos and have found every one except 2008 4.2 engine

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm out and about and cannot look it up, but would bet you can look at nearby years (say 2007 or 2009) with the same engine and the sensor should be in the same location. Even other vehicles with the 4.2 should have it in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an image of where your ECT is located on the GM 4.2L 6-cyl engine:

[image]